# Powershell HowTo get last day of 2 month ago

Tags: date, powershell, getdate

I've a script scheduled every 4th and 14th day of month.

when script starts on 4th, I need to get the last day of the previous month (easy, $a.AddDays(-5))

when script starts on 14th, I need to get the last day of 2 month before.

for example:

```
 14 april.

 I want to get:28 february 2013
```

how is it possible?
also I want to get the date in format yyyymmdd

UDPDATE:

Is it possible that your solution doesn't work well with the change of the year?

if I'm in january, $(get-date).month -1 results 0. so I did this:

```
 $datenow = Get-date
 if $datenow.day -eq 14
 $datenow.AddDays(-14)
```

then I calculate

```
 $LastDayInMonth = [System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth($(Get-date).Year, $(Get-date.Month))
 $datenow.AddDays(-$LastDayInMonth)
 $datestring = $datenow.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the date in a string:

```
$(get-date).Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

For getting the last day of two months prior:

```
if($(get-date).Day -eq 14){
    $LastDayInMonth = [System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth($(get-date).Year, $($(get-date).Month - 2))

}
```

---

**Update**

The line

```
$LastDayInMonth = [System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth($(get-date).Year, $($(get-date).Month - 2))
```

Uses the static method `DaysInMonth` in the System.DateTime class to get the days in the month of the month that is passed to it. It's documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx). It takes as input two parameters, the month as an integer, and the year as an integer as well.

In our case, we want 2 months before this month, so for the month parameter we pass in

```
$(get-date).month - 2
```

And that is surrounded in a parenthesis to make sure powershell does the calculation *and then* pass the result of the calculation. `get-date` is a powershell cmdlet that gives the current date and time as a .NET dateTime object, so we have all the properties and methods at our disposal.

The whole

```
[System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth()
```

is just the way of calling static methods in powershell.

---

**Update 2**

Once you get the last day in the month, you can concatenate the string by:

```
$LastDayInMonthString = "$($(get-date).AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyyMM"))$LastDayInMonth"
```

Comment: can you explain that line?

Comment: another doubt: after I got the value of $LastDayInMonth (i.e. 28) I want to get something like "20130228". is it possible? I know to use method .ToString("yyyyMMdd") but I don't know how to concatenate those numbers

Answer (score 3):

```
$(Get-Date).addDays(-$(Get-Date).Day).addMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```